# system ("rails generate migration")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, system

I would like to add to my existing table "participants" some columns from my application in ruby, without entering into db/migrate and write them by hand. I wrote:

```
system "rails generate migration AddCasesColumn foo :text"
```

and the system has rightly added the new migration "add_case_column", but with the methods "def up" and "down final" empty. I think because it does not know on which table to go to add the field.

How can I add "add_column: participants, attribute: type" in my migration from the controller ruby? Or is there another way to do this?

link to my old question: [Create a new migration from controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971331/create-a-new-migration-from-controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
system "rails generate migration AddCaseToParticipant case:string"
```

Comment: my migration is : system "rails generate migration AddCasesColumn foo:text " but the migration is empty. I think because it does not know on which table to go to add the field

Comment: see the answwer properly "rails generate migration AddCaseToParticipant case:string"

AddCaseToParticipan is the key